# How can I prevent output lines from wrapping in VS Code Jupyter Notebooks?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

When using Jupyter Notebooks within VS Code is it possible to stop the code cell result text from wrapping?

When querying wide dataframes (Eg 100 columns wide) the resulting text is unreadable due to the text wrapping and requires copying out to other text editors to be able to read the results.

Attached is a screenshot of a simple dataframe header that is wrapping over a couple of lines, once you're returning actual rows it's unusable.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

To disable word wrapping in the output of a Jupyter Notebook in VS Code, put the following in your [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson):

```json
"notebook.output.wordWrap": false,
```

Actually, the default value of the setting is `false`, so check if you have set it anywhere in your settings.json to `true`, and you should be able to remove that line to achieve the same thing.

If you're interested in a feature to make the word wrapping follow the current toggle of source code word wrapping (which is toggled by <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>), see this issue ticket: [Notebook text output should support the word wrap setting #116355](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/116355), which you can support by giving a thumbs up reaction, and subscribe to get notified about discussion and updates (but please avoid making noisy comments like "+1" / "bump").

Answer (score 1):

This could be a limitation of Jupyter's UI. I recommend you to see your data in variable explorer and data viewer. By clicking the `Variables` icon in the top side after running, you'll see a list of the current variables. For additional information of the variables, you can double-click on a row or use the `Show variable in data viewer` button to see a more detailed view.

[image]
[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to be possible with the current version or it doesn't work with a remote installation of jupyter.